# how to set dynamically height to element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to set dynamically height to element in my demo .I will tell you issue I am taking static or constant value of height in my demo .I take **250px** constant value

```
 #wrapper{
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nz1fzunlqzzz7uo/login_bg.png?dl=0);
    min-height: 250px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

But I need to add this height dynamically .I got height from this

```
$scope.hgt =$window.innerHeight/3;
alert($scope.hgt)
```

But I need to set **$scope.hgt** to min-height to #wrapper div dynamically?.I don't want to take static value of div height .I want to add dynamically .

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgawo

same thing i need to in angular what we do in jquery

```
$('#wrapper').css('height': $window.innerHeight / 3)
```

Comment: on what condition you need to add that height to element..& on what basis it should calculate?

Comment: when view load ..I need to set $window.innerHeight/3; to wrapper height.Mean when I run application I got the value of window height .then set the value of wrapper height

Comment: could you add your html please?

Comment: sory i forget to give html code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdgawo

Comment: where you added.could you please answer that question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79205/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-user944513).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could simply achieve this by own directive which will add css dynamically

**Markup**

```
<div id="wrapper" set-height>
  <h4 class="headerTitle">tell Mother name</h4>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('setHeight', function($window){
  return{
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.css('height', $window.innerHeight/3 + 'px');
        //element.height($window.innerHeight/3);
    }
  }
})
```

The better solution would be you could use ng-style directive that expects the values in JSON format.

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-style="{height: hgt+ 'px'}">
  <h4 class="headerTitle">tell Mother name</h4>
</div>
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNpJOY)

Comment: Hi, Can you help me in this issue plss ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33997547/4044949

Comment: Not working without px. It should be: 
element.css('height', $window.innerHeight/3 + 'px');

Comment: Correct..Thanks for heads up.. ;) but i think it should work..as codepen is working..updated answer..look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. Putting it in the codepen snippet won't show as the window size is small so it draws height from the min-height attribute. Test it out on a bigger window.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height: {{ hgt }}px" >
    <h4 class="headerTitle">tell Mother name</h4>
<div>
```

Comment: would you mind to update codepen? and what is the reason behind the it will not work in codepen?

Comment: I didn't say it won't work on Codepen. The height setting won't show because the window height on Codepen is 260px, and by dividing it by 3, you get a height of 86.67. But the min-height is 250px so the demonstration would not be successful. Anyway, this is the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGgYxV. Try it out.

Comment: Also, the window height of 260px in Codepen is for standard resolutions, but it could vary. Either way, do test it out in a full browser.

Comment: What makes you say it's not working? It seems to be working fine. Right click on the element and click on "inspect element". Check the CSS. It is attaching the required height to the element.

Answer (score 1):

set dynamically height with header footer to element?
**HTML**

```
<div class="content-wrapper" win-height>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('winHeight', function ($window) {
    return{
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(window).resize(function () {
                scope.winHeight();
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                scope.winHeight();
            }, 150);
            scope.winHeight = function () {
                element.css('min-height', angular.element(window).height() - 
                (angular.element('#header').height() + 
                 angular.element('#footer').height()));
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for applying other elements width to current element.

Width of the element which has the class name "container" will apply to div using flexibleCss angular js directive

```
<div flexible-width widthof="container">
</div>

myApp.directive('flexibleWidth', function(){

    return function(scope, element, attr) {
            var className = attr.widthof; 
            var classWidth = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.'+className)[0])[0].clientWidth;
            element.css({ 
                 width: classWidth+ 'px' 
             });
            };
   });
```