# Removing # from url in Angularjs while having .run in routes

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, angularjs-directive

Here is my `app.js`  route file in AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/login', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layouts/loginUser.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                    controller: 'logoutCtrl'
                })
                .when('/reset', {
                    title: 'Reset Password',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layouts/forgetPassword.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/invalidtoken', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invalidtoken.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                    role: '0'
                })

                //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])


        .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data, $http) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                     var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;

                    if (nextUrl == '/signin' || nextUrl == '/login' || nextUrl == '/verify' || nextUrl == '/register' || nextUrl == '/registered' || nextUrl == '/reset' || nextUrl == '/resetdone' || nextUrl == '/registersuccess')
                    {
                        $location.path(nextUrl);
                    }
                     else
                    {   

                        $location.path('/');
                    }      
            });
        });
```

Here i use .run to handle few requests.

I want to remove the # from the url to make the url pretty,

So i did like this to remove the # as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

and in the last line

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But nothing is happening to the application, it stills haves # in the url.

Even i tried [this](http://www.w3sanju.in/remove-hash-from-angularjs-url/) way

How can i achieve this ?

**Update :**

If i do

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data, $http, $locationProvider) {
```

and in the last line

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I am getting this error

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
```

I have tried in many ways, but none of them working.

**Update 2 :**

Or can anyone suggest a link of angularjs example which provides example without # in url ?

Comment: What browser you use?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Google Chrome latest is the one i use

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Is there any other possiblity to have like this ?

Comment: Have You put  <base href="/"> in  page head?

Comment: @Vivek yes, i tried that , but it didn't helped me

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara I referred that site only initially :)

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to use the `.run()` ? Add  `<base href="/" />` to you `<head>` or start of your body (first line) and then to match the logic of your .run() try this ( `.otherwise("/path")` to your `$routeProvider`):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/login', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layouts/loginUser.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                    controller: 'logoutCtrl'
                })
                .when('/reset', {
                    title: 'Reset Password',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layouts/forgetPassword.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/invalidtoken', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invalidtoken.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                    role: '0'
                })
. otherwise("/");
           $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

If you still face issues, I recommend https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

**Update:**

your `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Green Hopping</title>
        <link rel="shotcut icon" type="favicon.ico" href="public/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="icon" type="favicon.ico" href="public/images/favicon.ico" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-cloak="">
      <base href="/">
        <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                        when('/', {
                            title: 'Home',
                            templateUrl: 'home.html',
                            controller: 'homeCtrl'
                        })
                        .when('/login', {
                            title: 'Login',
                            templateUrl: 'login.html',
                            controller: 'authCtrl'
                        })
                        .when('/logout', {
                            title: 'Logout',
                            templateUrl: 'logout.html',
                            controller: 'logoutCtrl'
                        })
                        .when('/dashboard', {
                            title: 'Dashboard',
                            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
                            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
                        })          
                        .otherwise('/');              
                        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            }])
        .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $http, loginSrv) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    var orUseUrl = $location.path();
                    console.log(nextUrl);
                    if (nextUrl === '/logout'){loginSrv.logout();}
                    if (nextUrl === '/login'){loginSrv.login();}
                    if (loginSrv.loggedin === false) { $location.path('/'); } 
                    else { $location.path(nextUrl); }
            });
        });
        app.service("loginSrv",function(){
          var ls= this;
          ls.loggedin = false;
          ls.logout = function(){
            ls.loggedin = false;
          }
          ls.login = function(){
            ls.loggedin = true;
          }
        });
        app.controller("homeCtrl",function($scope, loginSrv){
          $scope.loggedin = loginSrv.loggedin;
        })     
        app.controller("dashboardCtrl",function($scope, loginSrv){
          $scope.loggedin = loginSrv.loggedin;
        })                    
        app.controller("authCtrl",function($scope, loginSrv){
          $scope.loggedin = loginSrv.loggedin;
        })
        app.controller("logoutCtrl",function($scope, loginSrv){
          $scope.loggedin = loginSrv.loggedin;
        })        
    </script>

</html>
```

All other templates are same like this. Copy paste the following for `home.html` , `login.html` , `dashboard.html` , `logout.html` . Plunker will not be able to show issues with routes for client side. Try this. This is completely functional code.

```
<div>
    <div><a href="/">Home</a> | 
    <a href="/login">Login</a> | 
    <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a> | 
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a></div>

    <div> This is from the home/login/dashboard/logout Controller. Loggedin: {{loggedin}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are methods in UI Router like `.onEnter`,`resolve`, `.onExit` that you can use for your benefit to do actions on entering or after exiting the url. It makes life easier.

Comment: But i wanted to use .run in the same time for some conditions, Is that not possible ?

Comment: Your were unable to remove `#` from your url and as per your `.run()` logic, if `"/wrongurl"` it goes to `"/"`. This can be done by `.otherwise("/")` directly and my provided code will do all that your given code does. This wont clash with `.html5Mode(true)` & `<base href="/">`. Why use `.run()` for that logic. If you want to do some other logic when entering a url, then why not use `$locationChangeStart` event & `path([path])` method(in `$location`) in `.run()`. `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location`. These have been made way easy in `ui.router` I mentioned. Check it out.

Comment: Do also let me know if my code helped for the same logic of run you are using.

Comment: Hey, if i do so , i am getting the blank page, and nothing is displaying :( Could you help me pls

Comment: That is a working code so should not faulter. It will faulted if you send wrong parameters or get query params. The URL and parameter has to match. What is you code now and what are you passing? Some syntactical or method usage issue probably

Comment: Updated the code above. Plunker does not allow checking issues with client side routes. There was no $locationProvider injection.

Comment: Made a minor code edit to suit your isLoggedin Variable. at `.run()` `if (authenticated)` function.

Comment: `<base href="/">` should be inside the body ?

Comment: I am getting this error.. :( TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalPath' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97504/discussion-between-sa-and-gary).

Answer (score 3):

try changing:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

To:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
   enabled: true,
   requireBase: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance receiving a 404 error ? Whenever you change the mode to html5history you have to tell the web server to always return the index page no matter what URL is requested. As the angular docs says here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a `<base>` tag is also important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application.

Have you tried doing that and configured it properly ?
Also remember that you have to specify the base entry href of your application for it to work like

```
  <base href="/" />
```

Comment: You mean to deal with .htaccess ?

Comment: Yeah i guess so - haven't work on the Apache server so you will have to check how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject `$locationProvider` in `.run` because providers are only available for `.config`

[This answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14771362/3716153) but you will have 2 issues:

1. You will need a check before `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`  as it will not work on IE 10 or older.

   ```
   if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   }
   ```
2. This will work only by removing the `#` when the user enters it in the url, i.e. if the users types `app/#/login` it will change to `app/login`. However, if the user bookmarks or copies the changed url `app/login` and enters that in the browser he will get an error as the server does not know about angular routing since it is client side only. In the thread I linked above you may find some comments on how to fix this.

Comment: I am not trying it in internet explorer, i am trying in chrome but this conditions is not working, i tried putting this inside and outside of the .run :(

Comment: Did you add <head> <base href="/"> </head>  as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620370/3716153 ?

Comment: Yeah, i added the same in the index.html file

Comment: If you have teamviewer, can you pls have a look on my code ?

Comment: It will be very hard to figure out the problem without seeing the code. Are you putting the above lines inside the .config ? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No, i wanted you to see my code via teamviewer... and i don't have any errors in console..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97473/discussion-between-gaafar-and-sa).

Comment: Team viewer is blocked on my network. Try adding $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); without the condition inside the .config function

Comment: Hey, are you there ?, could you pls come in chat/discussion

Comment: I guess you can find the hind if you see my code directly.. Any possiblity of it... Like ammyy or any other client to see my screen pls

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Try to share a fiddle or plunkr as I can't access team viewer. Or update the question with full code (js & html)

Comment: ok, i will try to add, you can't even able to see the code, if you reach home ? because my project is laravel based and it would take lot of time to construct the plunkr. but i will try to do

Comment: Here is the plunker ..http://plnkr.co/edit/X6xDNpMOXsssN3InkiCX?p=preview it contains only the app.js and the index.html file

Comment: Hi, you saw the plunkr ?

Comment: You are not injecting the '$locationProvider' in the config function like this:  app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

Comment: here http://plnkr.co/edit/EP3V8TfS24sZrtogcwaJ?p=preview use the app.js from this one

Comment: hey, i have changed accordingly.. but it was same.. It just 'Navigated to http://localhost/projects/myproject/' in console.. still blank page :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it is missing the service injection.
So in config section try injecting $locationProvider like below.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
            when('/login', {
                title: 'Login',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/layouts/loginUser.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/', {
                title: 'Login',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                controller: 'logoutCtrl'
            })
            .when('/reset', {
                title: 'Reset Password',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/layouts/forgetPassword.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/invalidtoken', {
                title: 'Login',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invalidtoken.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl',
                role: '0'
            })

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

Comment: No, # is not removing while i try this :(

Answer (score 0):

With html5mode you have to specify the base url in your html file for eg,

```
<base href="/">
```

Some links you can go through for your reference,

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: $locationProvider is missing in you config function and one more thing you need to have server side routing as well, to get what you want. reason behind is when locaitionchagnestart it will look for the url and will through you a new error so to avoid that error you need to implement server side routing.

Comment: even i tried by adding locationProvider.. It didn't worked me. Can you help me out pls

Answer (score 0):

it does not look possible you to remove hash-bang (#) from href manually, and it causes malfunction your router because hashbangs are enables browser not treat your state in order to send get request to an end point. browser does not fire a get request over #/route while it does over /route, unless you use your url provider in html5 mode. For html5 mode, add the line below into your app.config function:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
```