# Removing # from angularjs and making url pretty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to remove the # from the url

I have used the locationProvider and had  in the index.html

Locationprovider is given as

```
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
..
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Here is my script.js

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp

var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

This is the follow up of this question. I still didn't get the solution. I would accept both answer if it was answered.

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBdWvtqpTlTfOzIn9mYs?p=preview) of the example which i wanted to do.

Note :

```
This is my project folder

localhost/test/angular
```

So, i have this link in the about

```
localhost/test/angular/about
```

Request : Pls download the source from plunkr and have a try over it.

I am not getting any error but nothing appears in the body sections

Thanks

Comment: you forgot the link to the plunkr

Comment: Same question was asked just a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34265933/3933332

Comment: It seems that your app is not hosted by any server but you just accessing static files from your local machine?

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, i will refer

Comment: @IharKrasnik No, i am using it in php web server

Comment: Can you put the plunkr. I would want to see it. Follow this and in you have follow up queries please do not hesitate to ask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997547/removing-from-url-in-angularjs-while-having-run-in-routes Second you should be using `#/contact` as your url if your root is `"/"` which it seems it is.

Answer (score 2):

To link around your application using relative links, you will need to set this html code in the head of your document.

```
<base href="/your-base-if-needed">
```

or

```
<base href="/">
```

but the HTML5 mode set to true should automatically resolve relative links

Comment: I should have `<a href="#contact">` in html ?

Comment: Wowww.. Thanks.. It works great . wil accept in minute

Comment: But if i go the url directly i am getting page not found error.. help pls .. `http://localhost/test/an/about`

Comment: `<base href="/test/an/">`

Comment: Ok. That might be the problem I believe. Try putting the` <base href="/">` on the `index.html` or main page `of` `http://localhost/test/an/` and see if that makes a difference. Since this is angularjs it is completely separate from your backend files any ways. Is that correct?

Comment: @Gary And what should i update in the href of a tags ?

Comment: If i have `<base href="/">` in the index.html then no view is rendering in the page :(

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO Can you tell the reason pls

Comment: @Gary What should be the issue then

Comment: I am not sure. I generally have not faced an issue like this. However, in such cases it is always beneficial to split sites into different apps and put a base `/` on the path where you need, say at `http://localhost/test/an/` in this case . But it is always not a good idea since you will be loading angularjs at wrong places unnecessarily. Why do you really need this. If I know it I might be able to suggest an alternative. What purpose does it solve by putting the base path at `http://localhost/test/an/`? I would always prefer at `http://localhost/`

Comment: Incase of `http://localhost/test/an/` I am sure you might have a `http://localhost/test/an/index.html` or `index.php` or `index.aspx` at this location. Why not use `<base href='/'>` at this (`http://localhost/test/an/index.html`) place?