# How to resize element height to another element's height?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Based on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vuwgnfqw/1/ , how can the textareas' height be 50% of the flag's height? This should allow both stacked textareas to be as tall as the flag. You see, if the viewport is too narrow, the textareas are way too tall, and if the viewport is too wide, the flag is taller.

I used this code [how to set dynamically height to element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547547/how-to-set-dynamically-height-to-element) to modify with angular the height, but so far it is not dynamic, would like it to automatically resize accordingly if the page is resized. Basically I sinned adding DOM manipulation to the controller just to see if it worked

```
.controller('main', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#flag'));
    $scope.height = element[0].offsetHeight;
}]);
```

And in the HTML

```
<textarea class="playerName" rows="1" placeholder="APELLIDO" ng-style="{height: (height/2)-10 + 'px'}"></textarea>
```

And that worked, but it is not automatically refreshing with page resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a javascript solution (not much of an angular expert)

Add a class named `target` to the textarea tag and their parent.

Also apply an `overflow:hidden` property to these targets (this is in the event that the window is so tiny you will not see overflow contents)

Detect window resize and compute the width of the div that holds the image.

Half the width computed and apply it to your targets

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/vuwgnfqw/4/)

Comment: Still have to find an Angular solution to this, but repzero's was definitely a clever approach.